# Windows 7 x64 running on VMware Workstation 6.5.2 on Windows 7 x64 crashes host on resume

Tags: windows-7, vmware, crash, bsod

I'm running Windows 7 x64 on top of Windows 7 x64 using VMware Workstation 6.5.2.  If I suspend the VM and then try to resume the host BSODs.  I am able to successfully resume a different VM (running Windows 2003 x32).

[BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.HTML) says the culprit driver is vmx86.sys, at address vmx86.sys+3798 (its always this address, if that means anything to anyone). Any ideas?

Comment: This happens for me RELIGIOUSLY when I resume a suspended VM on the Win7 OS.  What really sucks is when I accidentally hit CTRL++Shift+S or something that does some sort of quick suspend and then I'm doomed to go through the BlueScreen of Death reboot sequence.  I do this dance at least 2 times a week now but I refuse to downgrade from Win7 (which I love love love).

Comment: It works perfectly for a WS2k3 VM I have (gets suspended, backed up and resumed every morning) but will fail every time for WS2k8 (32-bit) and Windows 7 x64...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Pointer** - VMWare Workstation 6.5.x still has problems running on NT 6.0 and 6.1 x64 platforms (Vista and Win7, respectively). Even their techies aren't sure what it's all about, but crash analysis suggests something about faulty communication between real and virtual kernels.

( Aggravating circumstance is that problem manifests itself in different ways - for instance, your ability to run (or resume) a different (x86) OS in VMWare, whereas even that isn't possible. )

**Possible workaround** - install and run WMVare in WinXP compatibility mode, always with "Run as admin" command. 
Note -- worked for booting x86 and x64 Debian kernel in VMWare after several VMWare crashes and reinstalls (and it still works, although it's a 'n00bish' solution)